# How to give multiple namespaces of salesforce in xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, salesforce, xml-namespaces

I have a response like below which I got from salesforce. I need to use xpath to retrieve the ProfileId.

```
<queryResponse xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">
   <result xsi:type="QueryResult">
      <done>true</done>
      <queryLocator xsi:nil="true"/>
      <records xsi:type="sf:sObject">
         <sf:type>User</sf:type>
         <sf:Id xsi:nil="true"/>
         <sf:Username>testuser@test.com</sf:Username>
         <sf:ProfileId>00e90000001aVwiAAE</sf:ProfileId>
         <sf:Name>user</sf:Name>
         <sf:LastName>test</sf:LastName>
         <sf:Email>user@test.com</sf:Email>
      </records>
      <size>1</size>
   </result>
</queryResponse>
```

I used an online xpath generator. It gave me the below xpath. But it seems to be wrong.

```
/queryResponse[@xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"]/result[@xsi:type="QueryResult"]/records[@xsi:type="sf:sObject"]/sf:ProfileId/text()
```

Comment: try `/queryResponse/result/records/sf:ProfileId/text()` or `/queryResponse[namespace-uri()="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"]/result[@xsi:type="QueryResult"]/records[@xsi:type="sf:sObject"]/sf:ProfileId/text()`

Comment: @Ushani How did you execute that XPath? What's the XPath processor here?

Comment: @har07 I used http://xmltoolbox.appspot.com/xpath_generator.html. . I need to know how to provide namespace itself in the xpath?

Comment: @Ushani not the generator that I asked, rather where did you use the generated XPath? You got the XML from salesforce, but did you execute the XPath somewhere in salesforce too? (sorry, I'm not familiar with salesforce)

Comment: Or did you execute your XPath using [that tool](http://xmltoolbox.appspot.com/xpathevaluator.html) as well?

Comment: Is this correct? 

/urn:partner.soap.sforce.com:queryResponse/urn:partner.soap.sforce.com:result[@xsi:type="QueryResult"]/urn:partner.soap.sforce.com:records[@xsi:type="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com:sObject"]/urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com:ProfileId/text()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath generator that you used seems didn't handle *default namespace* properly. Normally you need to declare a prefix (details of this step varies for different XPath processors), say `d`, referencing the default namespace URI which is "urn:partner.soap.sforce.com". Then use that prefix to reference elements in that namespace (wrapped for readability) :

```
/d:queryResponse
/d:result[@xsi:type="QueryResult"]
/d:records[@xsi:type="sf:sObject"]
/sf:ProfileId
/text()
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/663f294f3bc5d1e0fe3149742520c731)</kbd>**

It is possible to create a pure XPath that works the same as the previous XPath, but it will be too complex. To give you the taste of it, the following is almost equivalent to *part of* the previous XPath (starting from `/d:records` down) :

```
//*[local-name()='records' and namespace-uri()='urn:partner.soap.sforce.com']
   [@*[
        namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' and 
        local-name()='type' and 
        .="sf:sObject"
    ]]
 /*[local-name()='ProfileId' and namespace-uri()='urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com']
 /text()
```

There are many other possible XPath expressions to get `ProfileId` from such XML structure, one of the simplest, without knowing how to properly declare namespace prefix using your XPath processor, would be as follows :

```
//*[name()='sf:ProfileId']/text()
```

The above will return element where tag name equals 'sf:ProfileId' anywhere within the XML document.